# Connect another jabber to Gmail chat

Tags: gmail, chat, jabber, connection

I have a jabber account except Gmail. Is there any way to connect it to Gmail chat?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need a Jabber client like [Psi](http://psi-im.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Jabber is federated, like email.  You should just be able to add any @gmail.com users to your roster (buddy list) and talk with them -- the Jabber provider used doesn't matter, unless they're really backwards and don't have federation set up.